# Confusion regarding the Fermi-Dirac distribution and related formulas

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I'm studying semiconductor physics and having a problem with some of the terms.

The definition we were given in class for the Fermi-Dirac distribution is:

$$f_{FD}(E)
 = \frac{1}{1+e^\frac{E-E_f}{kT}}
$$

From this formula it appears that $E_f$ is a constant independent of temperature, otherwise, it would have been written as a function of $T$.

But then, there are the formulas for the intrinsic fermi levels:
$$E_i-E_V
 = \frac{E_g}{2}+\frac{3}{4}kT\ln\left(\frac{m_p^*}{m_n^*}\right)
$$
$$E_f-E_i
 = \frac{kT}{2}\ln\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)
 = kT\ln\left(\frac{n_i}{p}\right)
 = kT\ln\left(\frac{n}{n_i}\right)
$$
Here $E_f$ changes with temperature? Is that the same $E_f$ from the Fermi-Dirac distribution function?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to show equations instead of images. Images are not accessible to everyone.

Comment: Also, as a small aside, there any many instances in physics where we do not explicitly write out variable dependences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends whether you are keeping the number of particles fixed or not. Usually we write
$$
f(\mu, T,E)= \frac 1{1+\exp\{(E-\mu)/kT\}},
$$
where $\mu$ is the *chemical potential*. Then the total number of particles is 
$$
N=\int dE g(E) f(\mu,T,E).
$$
Here $g(E)$ is the energy density of states.
If we want $N$ to stay fixed as we vary $T$, then $\mu$ will have to depend on $T$. It may be however that our device is set up (by connecting to a reservoir of particles)  so that it is $\mu$ that remains fixed and  then $N$ will depend on $T$.  The Fermi energy $E_F$ is really the value of $\mu$ at $T=0$, but people are rather casual about distinguishing between $\mu$ and $E_F$.

Comment: For semiconductors, a good article is Mark R.A. Shegelski, American Journal of Physics 72, 676 (2004); doi: 10.1119/1.1629090 - "The chemical potential of an ideal intrinsic semiconductor".